# A rapidly update progressbar in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a progress animation, which is updated by `requestAnimationFrame` and variable `progress`. It has a high update frequency (I may update it about 60 times in a second).

If I change the `progress` through `style` like this:

```
<div className="progress-line" style={{transform: `translateX(${progress})`}}></div>
```

it may trigger React render a lot.

Is there a better way to do this? Maybe changing `refs` like:

```
_ref.style.transform = `translateX(${progress})`
```

Comment: I am curious why do you need to update a progress bar 60 times a second?!

Comment: Using a ref to the dom is definitely a way of doing this more efficiently. Even if react will optimize the dom updates, they are inherently asynchonous.